# Django 3 - ORM "AND" logic in filtering

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a Query.

```
qu = Product.objects 
        .filter(color = 'black')
        .filter(color = 'white')
        .all()
```

That gives me "And" logic which I'm looking for. Now I want to pass dict of criterions.

```
my_crit = { 'color': 'black', 'color': 'white' }

    qu = Product.objects 
            .filter(**my_crit)
            .all()
```

That gives me OR, which is bad for me. So I tried Q.

```
crit1 = Q(color='black')
crit2 = Q(color='white')

        qu = hello = Product.objects 
                .filter(crit1 & crit2)
                .all()
```

This returns query with 0 results. So the question is - how can I use filter chain (AND logic) with dynamic inputs? (my own dict, etc).

Comment: Did you try `getattr` method ?

Comment: No, can u reffer plz?

Comment: @Barrandov Firstly `{ 'color': 'black', 'color': 'white' }` you cannot have the same key twice in the same dictionary. Secondly `crit1 & crit2` this is an impossible condition how can an attribute (`color`) have two different values (`black` and `white`) at the same time? Talking about your first query it appears that you don't show your actual queries it appears that you have a **many relation** to some model and are chaining filters on that which will give you the behaviour you talk about.

Comment: Abdul, thank u for the answer. Yes I am using M2M model.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the "__in" lookup parameter.

```
colors = ("black", "white")
queryset.filter(color__in=colors).all()
```

See more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#in

Comment: it wont create “and” logic

Comment: I did not know you have a m2m relationship, it looks like a regular CharField. Could you please add the models to the question?